# Assist with MySQL SELECT

Tags: mysql

I'm sitting with this SELECT statement

I got ONE product separated into 5 products, each with a column telling how many you should order to get it for that price.

What I want is, for instance, if I'm ordering 54, I should get the price from 50.

If I'm ordering 100 or 101 etc.. I should get the price from 100.. and so on.

Here's my SELECT so far ..

```
SELECT  
entity.entity_id AS "ID",
entity.value AS "Name",
qty_price.qty AS "Pcs",
qty_price.value AS "Price"
FROM `mg_catalog_product_entity_tier_price` qty_price 
JOIN `mg_catalog_product_entity_varchar` entity 
ON qty_price.entity_id = entity.entity_id 
WHERE entity.entity_id = 300 
AND entity.value = (SELECT name FROM `mg_catalog_product_flat_1` WHERE `mg_catalog_product_flat_1`.entity_id  = entity.entity_id)
LIMIT 10;
```

EDIT: Here is the screenshot that was mentioned in the comments to the replies:
[image: Screenshot of Statement and output]

Comment: Maybe you can also explain how your tables look like

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please try to put at least a little effort into the quality of your writing. This is a professional site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need something like this (note, I am not referring to your exact tables):

```
SELECT 
    item_id, 
    item_quantity, 
    (
        SELECT base_price 
        FROM prices p 
        WHERE 
            o.item_id = p.item_id AND 
            o.item_quantity >= p.base_quantity 
        ORDER BY p.base_quantity
        LIMIT 1
    ) FROM orders o
```

Here orders is your table of orders, it has item_id and quantity. Prices is a static table having item_id, quantity and base price per item at that quantity. So if you have
`17 6` in orders (meaning you are buying 6 of an item with id=17) and `17 1 3.50`, `17 5 3.29`, `17 100 3.01` (`item_id, quantity, base_price`) you will get `17 6 3.29` as a result.

Comment: Try to have a look on this: it-guiden.dk/downloads/SQL.png

Answer (score -1):

You may need to rethink your table design. You probably want to have a  `mg_catalog_product_entity_tier_price` table that lists both a minimum and maximum number of items that can be ordered to get that price tier. Then the statement is simple.

Otherwise, this would involve using logic like `select max(prices.items_required) from prices where order_qty<items_required_for_tier`. This would find the largest item quantity from the price list where the number of items ordered is less than the actual order size.

Comment: I'm sorry that my question might seem badly described ..

I wasn't able to upload the screeshot .. :(

I'm loooking into the first answer right away . .:)

I'm just uploading a screenshot to my own webserver, because it would be much more informative for all of you if you see the SQL statement + the outcome

Comment: You probably wanted to comment on the original post, not my answer. 

In any case, the `Order by base_quantity` combined with the `Limit 1` is the same as using max(base_quantity). I still think that this is a bad idea for any actual query, since if it is deployed, it will run much more slowly on large data sets than storing a max and min items in your table.